# How to convert a string to a function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've been working on [Clojure question 135 Infix Calculator](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/135), basically a simplified infix to prefix arithmetic calculator:

```
(= 7  (__ 2 + 5))
```

I solved the problem as specified. But that got me wondering - what if the argument had been supplied as a string - how would I get it to work?

```
(= 7  (__ "2 + 5"))
```

Obviously I'd start with a **split**, then munch through the result:

```
(clojure.string/split "2 + 5" #"\s")
user=> ["2" "+" "5"]
```

But how would I convert the "+" to a function call? This isn't going to work:

```
("+" 2 5)
user=> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be 
cast to clojure.lang.IFn <snip>
```

Enlightenment sought....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the resolve function

```
((resolve (symbol "+")) 1 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `load-string` or `read-string`. That's something like `READ-FROM-STRING` in common lisp, which adhere to the principle of 'Code is Data', treats the string as codes - evaluate and return the value.

```
user=> (class (load-string "+"))
clojure.core$_PLUS_
user=> (read-string "+")
+
user=>
```

then you can simply use it.